# SQL Server - best way to estimate size of result set of query in MB before returning the data?

Tags: sql-server, database

Given a query that queries multiple tables, is there a way to calculate the size of the result set **before** returning the full result set?

My best guess so far is to write a query that sums the size of all columns multiplied by row count to get an estimation. Maybe have a metatable that stores the average size of each column for each table, updated by a stored procedure each morning to get the average size (since some columns can be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`)

Comment: It would depend quite a bit on what you intend to use the result for. Your proposed estimate is more or less the one used by the optimizer itself when it has to take a stab at memory grants, and it can give very poor results if columns are generally much larger than the data they actually store. Does that matter? Well, it depends. If this is just for an ETA for end users, spending a lot of effort and I/O on a great estimate would seem counterproductive, as in, there are easier ways of doing that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Limiting Data returned. Since our databases have the potential to return several GB's of data and bottleneck the whole system. We have applications that can query the database outside the DBMS

Comment: You could try to do something with the `execution plan` that will have some estimates in it, but I don't think ones that contain the actual size of the data. You can `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` but it is going to be messy. Perhaps combining that with the meta data that's already stored in SQL about each table?

Comment: It sounds then like your issue is not so much estimating the result size accurately, but limiting the impact of unexpectedly huge queries on the system. That can be done with things like Resource Governor, and judicious application of views, or with active monitoring of expensive queries (lots of options for that) and killing the offending queries (or sending a signal that applications will respect -- any pre-estimate you'd do would also need such a kill-or-agree-to-stop mechanism, after all.)

Comment: If you actually want to physically limit the queries from returning more than X rows, you could use `SET ROWCOUNT`, but tampering with the results sounds like a bad idea, even if it is to limit unreasonable queries. As a developer I'd rather have a clear error signal than query results that were creatively edited by some mechanism.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Does Resource Governor have the ability to limit just queries? Or does it limit everything?

Comment: It limits resources (memory, CPU, I/O) per pool, and you determine what pool a session ends up in with a classifier. This classifier can use any property of the session to determine the pool, but it can't dynamically assign pools per query executed. So you could, for example, limit all requests from your potentially power-hungry application to use no more than 10% CPU and I/O, but that restriction would then apply to all queries from that source.

Answer (score 0):

You create a table with query results and run sp_spaceused. Here is my solution. You can refer.

```
SELECT *
INTO tablename
FROM ...

Exec sp_spaceused 'tablename'

Drop tablename
```

Comment: How is "tablename" declared? I get  --Unknown object type 'tablename'-- when running this

Comment: Be careful with this, because obviously, the whole query is executed and the results persisted to disk. Technically it does measure the size before returning data to the client, but there's no estimating going on here.